# Common Methods for Repository Pattern w/ Unit of Work

Tags: .net-core, c#-7.3

I have a project where I am attempting to use Unit of Work w/ Repository design pattern for performing CRUD operations using EF Core. FWIW, I am on .NET Core 2.2.

### Question:

Is there a way for me to create an (abstract) class to implement certain operations for some models but not for all? In my current thought process, I want to do this in CountRepository class. I'd like to return the entity records from TypeA, TypeB and TypeC - which satisfy specific conditions for CountDate and XCount fields.

### Layout and Details:

#### Solution.EFProject

- Models\

  - TypeA.cs
  - TypeB.cs
  - TypeC.cs
  - OtherModel.cs
- BaseEntity.cs
- BaseTypeEntity.cs
- Context.cs

#### Solution.DAL

- Core\

  - Repositories\

    1. IRepository.cs
    2. ICountRepository.cs
    3. ITypeARepository.cs
    4. ITypeBRepository.cs
    5. ITypeCRepository.cs
    6. IOtherModelRepository.cs
  - IUnitOfWork.cs

.

- Persistence\

  - Repositories\

    1. Repository.cs
    2. **CountRepository.cs**
    3. TypeARepository.cs
    4. TypeBRepository.cs
    5. TypeCRepository.cs
    6. OtherModelRepository.cs
  - UnitOfWork.cs

#### *Solution.EFProject.BaseEntity.cs*

```
public abstract  class BaseEntity
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public BaseEntity()
    {
        Enabled = true;
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

#### *Solution.EFProject.BaseCountEntity.cs*

```
public abstract class BaseCountEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime CountDate { get; set; }
    public long XCount { get; set; }
}
```

#### *Solution.EFProject.Models.TypeA.cs*

```
public class TypeA : BaseCountEntity 
{
  public int TypeAId { get; set; }
  public long ACount { get; set; }
}
```

#### *Solution.EFProject.Models.TypeB.cs*

```
public class TypeB : BaseCountEntity 
{
  public int TypeAId { get; set; }
  public long B1Count { get; set; }
  public long B2Count { get; set; }
}
```

#### *Solution.EFProject.Models.TypeC.cs*

```
public class TypeB : BaseCountEntity 
{
  public int TypeAId { get; set; }
  public long C1Count { get; set; }
  public long C2Count { get; set; }
  public long C3Count { get; set; }
}
```

#### *Solution.DAL.Persistence.Repositories.Repository.cs*

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        _entities = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    // GET method(s) on <TEntity> collection
    // ADD method(s) on <TEntity> collection
    // UPDATE method(s) on <TEntity> collection
    // REMOVE method(s) on <TEntity> collection
}
```

Comment: Is this better asked over on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? This appears that it would generate opinion based answers

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. I'd like to think, as on OP, that my question was asked in the different spirit. Validating my implementation would be out of the scope of the question. I'm just trying to see if there is a way for me to avoid code duplication & increase maintainability, by not having to duplicate the same functions multiple times used to retrieve the records based on the properties of "BaseCountEntity" class. I don't mind to move my question elsewhere, if the moderators still think that, I should.

Comment: Same functions can exists for different reasons. If you will "dry" them only because their code looks same, then you will introduce maintainability problem. Instead I would suggest to duplicate all code and "dry" it only when you will do first changes to the code and recognise a common pattern.

Comment: @Fabio I think I see what you are saying. But that is not the case for me in this instance. I figured out a solution, and would try to post the answer here soon.

Comment: @ablaze the "generic repository" is an antipattern. A repository that simply aliases the ORM's methods doesn't offer anything on top of a DbContext, assuming it doesn't introduce serious errors like loading everything in memory before filtering. If you look at the methods you wrote you'll realize how similar they are to any DbContext and its configuration.

Comment: @ablaze a *real* repository offers methods that actually abstract complex data operations, like constructing a proper object graph for an entity and its line items before persisting it, or hiding complex queries from callers. A controller doesn't need to know how many `Include`s are needed after all, or how the `Where` clause is constructed for yesterday's mango ice cream sales

Comment: @ablaze as for the base entity, soft deletes can be implemented using [EF's global filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) while the creation date is best implemented as a default value in the database. Those are implementation details that leaked to the final model